# Why will this simple C program not run?

Tags: c, string, if-statement

This code will not run. Can somebody tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main (){
    char user[7];  
    printf("Username\n");
    scanf("%s",user);
    if(user == 'admin'){
        printf("Hello World");
    }else{
        printf("Bad");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `if (user == 'admin')` is wrong. Use `strcmp`. Btw, in your case it is `int main(void)`. However, _This code will not run. Can somebody tell me why?_ is offtopic.

Comment: You can't compare things like in Javascript or Java.

Comment: Using `%s` like that is a nice invitation for the user to type in more than 6 characters and mess everything up.

Comment: @PopescuAlexandruConstantin Actually, it's the same situation as with java here

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example. You need to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare strings. strcmp() returns 0, if the strings are equal.
If the max input length is known, then you should also use length specifier in scanf or one of the suggestion listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c), to prevent a buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    char user[7];  
    printf("Username:\n");
    scanf("%6s", user);

    if(!strcmp(user, "admin"))
    {
        printf("Hello World");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Bad");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you are comparing two strings the wrong way. You need to use [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824838/what-does-strcmp-exactly-returns-in-c/34825545#34825545) answer to see what `strcmp` returns in C.

To make your program work, change the line

```
if (user == 'admin')
```

to

```
if (strcmp (user, "admin") == 0)
```

Also, using `scanf` might be a bit dangerous, in rare cases. I prefer using `fgets` for strings. To use `fgets`, do:

```
fgets (user, sizeof (user), stdin);
```